# C++ program hangs on imshow command

Tags: c++, opencv, imshow

I have some C++-Code which for some reason keeps hanging.
This is the code:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv; 


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

cout <<"started";
Mat im(256, 256, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(255));
for (int j = 0; j < 255; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 255; k++) {

        if (k > j) {
            cv::Mat black(im, cv::Rect(j, k, 1, 1));
            black = cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0);
        }

    }
}

Mat image2;
//cvtColor(image, image2, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cout<<"started";
imshow("", im);
waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

Now, I have been trying this for 3 days now, literally erasing every single line of that code and putting it back in, it all comes down to:

must bei the 
    imshow()
which causes the program to hang so that the image does not show.

The strange thing is, I copied verbatim out of an older program of mine, it worked, even worked in the new project for a day and then SUDDENLY started hanging, meaning the program just keeps running and running without any result and it cannot be shut down.

Obviously I must be overlooking sth really basic here, but  I simply cannot find it.

Help, please?

My OS is Ubuntu 15.10. Also, I just tried out SSteves answer => same problem. 
So it must be some kind of memory leak and not my code, right? How on earth do you fix memory leaks?

Comment: I don't see an imshow command in your code?

Comment: Was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cv::imshow sometimes is very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837796/cvimshow-sometimes-is-very-slow)

Comment: There are **several** problems with your code. What exactly were you trying to do? Can you explain the algorithm?

Comment: The algorithim pretty much only gives me a quadratic mat image, half of which is white the other half is black, with the two halves being separated diagonally. This image would be "im". I have tested that, this part works. Even showing the image workend fine untill two days ago.

Comment: Also, it would be nice if someone who actually downvotes a question would at least have the decency to mention why he did it, otherwise I cannot even fix what was so annoying to the person.

Comment: To explain the algorithm further: I loop  through a Mat  (initially completely white) with of size 256x256 pixel by pixel and draw a rectangle of size one pixel if and only if the y-coordinate is bigger than the x-coordinate

Comment: Have you tried to put a non-empty string as window name in imshow?

Comment: Yes. same result. And it has now been hanging for an hour, so I suppose it is not a duplicate as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works for me and does what you describe.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Mat image(256, 256, CV_8UC1, Scalar(255));
    for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) { //index goes to < 256, not < 255
        for (int k = j + 1; k < 256; k++) { //start loop at j + 1 to eliminate if (k > j) test
            Mat black(image, Rect(j, k, 1, 1));
            black = Scalar(0); //only one value in Scalar since this is a single-channel image
        }       
    }
    cv::imshow("", image);
    // wait for key
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: black/white diagonal]

I made a couple small changes:

- The loop index test should be `< 256`, not `< 255` unless you specifically don't want to modify the last row or column.
- You can start the inner loop with `int k = j + 1` to avoid unnecessary loop iterations and the `if (k > j)` test.
- You're setting `black` to a three-channel Scalar value. Mine still works when I changed it to `Scalar(0, 0, 0)` but you still shouldn't do that.

I tried your code and it also works. You don't mention what OS you're running. I'm running OS X.

Comment: I copypasted your code verbatim, => still same problem. My OS is Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Is it possible that the window is displayed but not visible? I have had situations where the OpenCV window appears behind another window. Or maybe you had a second monitor connected at some point and it being displayed there.

Comment: no. no second monitor and no, window is not invisible either.

Comment: Not sure what else to suggest. The code is right so it must be something with your system configuration.