# Android Cocos2dx Crash

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have made game in cocos2dx for ios device. Now I want to port it for android but, the code which works fine for ios is crashing for android. The eclipse shows 3 types of logCat outputs which are as follows.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
1) 11-27 10:41:05.168: W/SharedBufferStack(4417): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=302, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
2) 11-27 10:41:36.448: D/lights(248): set_light_backlight: brightness=255
11-27 10:41:41.518: I/InputDispatcher(248): Application is not responding: Window{2b452080 org.cocos2dx.Saburbia_android/org.cocos2dx.Saburbia_android.Saburbia_android paused=false}. 5000.4ms since event, 5000.4ms since wait started
11-27 10:41:41.518: I/WindowManager(248): Input event dispatching timed out sending to org.cocos2dx.Saburbia_android/org.cocos2dx.Saburbia_android.Saburbia_android
11-27 10:41:41.528: I/Process(248): Sending signal. PID: 4417 SIG: 3
11-27 10:41:41.528: I/dalvikvm(4417): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
11-27 10:41:41.728: I/Process(248): Sending signal. PID: 248 SIG: 3
11-27 10:41:41.728: I/dalvikvm(248): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
11-27 10:41:41.748: I/dalvikvm(248): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-27 10:41:41.748: I/Process(248): Sending signal. PID: 355 SIG: 3
11-27 10:41:41.748: I/dalvikvm(355): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
11-27 10:41:41.758: I/dalvikvm(355): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-27 10:41:41.758: I/Process(248): Sending signal. PID: 320 SIG: 3
11-27 10:41:41.758: I/dalvikvm(320): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
11-27 10:41:41.758: I/dalvikvm(320): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-27 10:41:41.968: D/dalvikvm(248): GC_EXPLICIT freed 952K, 49% free 6943K/13447K, external 3286K/4888K, paused 78ms
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): ANR in org.cocos2dx.Saburbia_android (org.cocos2dx.Saburbia_android/.Saburbia_android)
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): Load: 7.93 / 7.92 / 7.79
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): CPU usage from 27270ms to 0ms ago:
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 99% 4417/org.cocos2dx.Saburbia_android: 99% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 0% 3877/com.google.android.apps.maps: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 418 minor
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 0% 3957/com.svox.pico: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 678 minor
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 0% 248/system_server: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 0% 1679/com.sonyericsson.customization: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 283 minor
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 0% 3647/com.sonyericsson.devicemonitor: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 179 minor
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 0% 121/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 0% 320/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 0% 3731/com.sonyericsson.android.datamonitor: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 25 minor
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 100% TOTAL: 100% user + 0% kernel
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): CPU usage from 461ms to 976ms later:
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 98% 4417/org.cocos2dx.Saburbia_android: 98% user + 0% kernel
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 96% 4418/HeapWorker: 96% user + 0% kernel
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 3.8% 248/system_server: 1.9% user + 1.9% kernel
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 1.9% 291/InputDispatcher: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 1.9% 442/er$SensorThread: 1.9% user + 0% kernel
11-27 10:41:42.518: E/ActivityManager(248): 100% TOTAL: 98% user + 1.9% kernel
11-27 10:41:42.518: I/InputDispatcher(248): Dropping event because the pointer is not down.
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

3) and third reason is unknows as it shows meny memory address in logCat.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I am using libcurl for web calls and pThread for threading. This game also have Facebook Integration which is done using Facebook API for mobile (Hackbook).

After facebook login, the native code connects to the server using libcurl and makes about 30 http calls using pThread so that rendering thread should not be paused for getting the response from server. Still while this loading is going on the logcat shows any of these 3 logs and restarts loading from the start. There are http request present in game also which are executed using pThreads but in game also it shows any of this 3 log and crashes randomely.

The same code works fine for the ios build. I am not able to find why its not running properly for Android. Please suggest if any rules have to be followed for android porting.

I am using versions as follows.
Android NDK : r8b
Cocos2dx : 2.0.3
Eclipse : 3.6.2
Android version : 2.2
System : Ubuntu 10.0.4
Devices : SonyEricsson NeoV (android2.3.4), Samsung Galaxy SII (android4.0.3).

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Read this it may help u : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458404/android-cpu-may-be-pegged-bug

Answer (score 0):

Try to find memory issue in iPhone,because auto-release code might not working correctly.
  Also use the NDK stack for more detail error.
Update:Another way to track ndk stack on remote use the https://www.crittercism.com
Thank you.